# How to output date to a text file, filename in Windows XP

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

I have tried many ways of doing this in a batch file, although when outputting to a filename, I get "/" in them, so it can't output it to a text file, I realize they differ, so one which works in XP and Vista / 7 would be handy

```
E.g. Set FileDate=%date:/=%
```

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I had written it a while ago.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set today=!date:/=-!
set now=!time::=-!
set millis=!now:*.=!
set now=!now:.%millis%=!

echo hello world > my-file-!today!_!now!.txt
```