# Batch: for /f +xcopy output - Save to .log

Tags: scripting, batch-file, scripting-language

I have the next script, and I need it to save all the xcopy files copy outputs to one log file,

```
:tmdeploy
title Deploying Edithor - %deployer%
set src_folder=S:\ApliTelinver\Compilacion\Edithor 10.5\CompilacionQA
set dst_folder=S:\ApliTelinver\Ambientes-Edithor\Sincronizacion\Test\Test-Mantenimiento
set filelist=filelist-tm.txt
echo Origen: %src_folder%
echo Destino: %dst_folder%
echo.
REM for /f %%i in (%filelist%) DO xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" > "%dd%.log"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" > "%dd%.log"
)
echo.
pause
goto end
```

The problem is that I only get the last file copy in the output. And how to properly do a timestamp for .log file?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the appended redirection operator, `>>` instead of `>`.

So, your `for` loop will look like this:

```
REM for /f %%i in (%filelist%) DO xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" >> "%dd%.log"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" >> "%dd%.log"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, and which is the proper timestamp way to do it, so my log file will have the right timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean? And where is `%dd%` set?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244963/how-to-output-date-to-a-text-file-filename-in-windows-xp/6245000#6245000) help?

Comment: It does, helps a lot, thanks, but its not doing minutes output.

Comment: It's doing for me. I just got `my-file-08-06-2011_18-12-06.txt`

Comment: Strange I got: 08-06-2011_13.log

Comment: @BoDiE2003: From the fact that @adarshr gets the correct name and you don't I presume that you are obtaining `dd` based on the current date & time and and the issue is related to how the date/time output is formatted. Seems like the formula does not apply well in your case because the date/time string is formatted differently from how it is expected by the formula. So, seconding @adarshr's request here, please show us the definition of `dd`.

Comment: This is what Im using right now for example to do a `for` loop and save the output to a log file: `xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" >> "logs\t3-!today!_!now!.log"` And I'm using the definition of `!today!_!now!` as @adarshr is explaining in his post: `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set today=!date:/=-!
set now=!time::=-!
set millis=!now:*.=!
set now=!now:.%millis%=! `

Comment: What are the outputs of `date /t` and `time /t` on your machine?

Comment: And those of `echo %date%` and `echo %time%` also please.